# How to add document in Apache Solr (SolrJ ) using Java API on specific core

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrj

How we can add data to a specific core running on Apcache Solr.
Currently i have this piece of code, and it adds data on a single core, what if we have multiple cores running with having same field names, how solar decides to write in which core, because this piece of code is Nebulous !

We are nowhere defining , which core/collection/index !!!

```
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument;

import java.io.IOException;

public class SolrjPopulator {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SolrServerException {
    HttpSolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr");
    for(int i=0;i<1000;++i) {
      SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
      doc.addField("cat", "book");
      doc.addField("id", "book-" + i);
      doc.addField("name", "The Legend of the Hobbit part " + i);
      server.add(doc);
      if(i%100==0) server.commit();  // periodically flush
    }
    server.commit();
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `server.add(doc);` consider using `server.add(doc, 10000);`. This way solr will flush every periodically every 10 seconds.

Comment: I m getting following error in above code:
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at...
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated....
How to resolve this error??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cores will have different URLs and you can use those URLs in code:

```
HttpSolrServer server0 = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr/core0");
HttpSolrServer server1 = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr/core1");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use "collection" parameter to define which core you want to use:

```java
server.add("core0", doc);
server.commit("core0");
```

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/7_1_0//solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrClient.html#add-java.lang.String-org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument-